# I have intrusive thoughts about God

Tags: gods, belief

So I have a psychological problem where I get intrusive thoughts. These intrusive thoughts are usually about God/Devi's. These thoughts are really bad. They consist of sexual thoughts about the Devi's sometimes and also bad curse words that also go to the Devi's.

I cannot control these thoughts. The more I try, the harder they come. I know I have to seek professional help for these thoughts, but in the mean time I have a few questions:

1. Is God getting angry with me with these thoughts?
2. Is this contributing to my karma? Is this adding bad karma to me?
3. Can God curse me because of these thoughts? For example, cursing something close to me so I can never see it or do a certain activity again?

These are my questions. I want to say again that I really can't control these thoughts and I try everyday to. These thoughts are really affecting me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP admits they have a psychological problem. It needs a professional help. Any reply given in between without knowing the state of the OP can harm them. We are not professionals who give medical advice. Questions involve advice on thoughts and is asking for opinions. We are not professionals. Personal advice and medical advice are also off-topic.